# What are the differences between -v an -V to get the Version of software in Ubuntu?

Tags: versions

I'm always confused to get the version of software installed in Ubuntu. To prevent from full typing to get the version like `<software> --version` instead I always use something like `<software> -V`.

But the problem is that not for all software it works. For some I've to use `<software> -v` and for some, I've to use full `--version` to get the version.

**For example**

wget, gedit, nano, mysql`, etc all work with **-V** (Capital V)

but **Php**, **Skype** and may be others never worked with **-V** instead I've to use **-v** (small v) to get the version:

```
php -V
Usage: php [options] [-f] <file> [--] [args...]
   php [options] -r <code> [--] [args...]
   php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -R <code> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
   php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -F <file> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
   ...

php -v
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Dec 12 2013 04:27:25) 
...
```

Some work with both **-v** and **-V** like **firefox**. And some even don't work with either of **-v** or **-V** like **totem**, **wine** and **google-chrome**.

- Why there is this much difference?
- Since -V is always preferred to get the version of the software, why there is no any standard? or is there any standard that I don't know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to get the version of system-installed software is to use your package manager tools!

`--version` is not a reliable way to do so, for several reasons:

- Not all programs have executables. Libraries are a good example. You can't check your kernel version using `linux --version`, as there is no such command. Or your video driver version.
- Not all executables have command-line arguments. Most do, but GUI programs don't need to, and some don't.
- `--version`, as any command-line argument, is application-dependent. It depends on the developer to implement it, and there is no "standard" per-se, merely a convention. As you've noticed with `-v|-V`, it is not consistent. Even `--help` is not universal.
- The format output of `--version` is not consistent either. Some print a single line, some print several. Some print the version number *only*, some print the program name too.

That said, there *is* a standard, consistent way to get the installed version of *any* software in your system: **ask the *system*, not the sofware!**

Thanks to its Debian heritage, Ubuntu has a powerful package management system called `apt` (actually, `dpkg`). It controls installed packages, its dependencies, available repositories, *and versions*.

There are several package-management tools and front-ends you can use to query your installed packages. Here are some that display the version:

- `apt-cache policy <package>`
- `dpkg --list <package>` (you can use wildcards!)

And if you don't know what package a given command belongs to, you can find out in several ways:

- `apt-cache search '<name>'`
- `apt-file search '<path>'`

And the output is always consistent, reliable, standard, because you're not asking individual software made by distinct developers, you're querying your system about its status.

As an example, here's the result of a search of *all* the commands your mentioned in a *single output*:

```
$ dpkg --list wget gedit nano mysql-server skype php? firefox totem wine google-chrome*
```

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                       Version                    Description
+++-==========================-==========================-====================================================================
ii  firefox                    42.0+build2-0ubuntu0.12.04 Safe and easy web browser from Mozilla
ii  gedit                      3.4.1-0ubuntu1             official text editor of the GNOME desktop environment
ii  google-chrome-stable       46.0.2490.80-1             The web browser from Google
ii  mysql-server               5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2    MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
ii  nano                       2.2.6-1                    small, friendly text editor inspired by Pico
ii  php5                       5.3.10-1ubuntu3.21         server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
ii  skype                      4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1  client for Skype VOIP and instant messaging service
ii  totem                      3.0.1-0ubuntu21.1          Simple media player for the GNOME desktop based on GStreamer
ii  wget                       1.13.4-2ubuntu1.2          retrieves files from the web
ii  wine                       1.4-0ubuntu4.1             Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (meta-package)
```

Comment: Agreed.. **Ask the system, Not the software!**

Comment: Great answer. Thanks! But, I have one query: while finding a version using `--version` for Google chrome, I can use either `google-chrome --version` or `google-chrome-stable --version`. Both give the same result. However, in the case of `dpkg --list`, why does only `dpkg --list google-chrome-stable` work? For `dpkg --list google-chrome`, I'm getting `dpkg-query: no packages found matching google-chrome` error!!

Comment: @Milan: Because Google Chrome (the software) **package** is `google-chrome-stable`, and that package _contains_ two **executables**, `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable` and `/usr/bin/google-chrome` (and both are symlinks which which ultimately point to `/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome`). So you can either ask the software invoking their executables, or ask `dpkg` using its _package_ name.

Comment: @MestreLion Thanks a lot again for your reply. Got your point. Just to understand more, I noticed that `/usr/bin/google-chrome` is a soft link to `/etc/alternatives/google-chrome` which is a soft link to `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable`. On the other hand `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable` is a soft link to `/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome`. So, where does Linux stores the package name? I mean how does it confirms whether the package name is `google-chrome-stable` or `google-chrome`?

Comment: @Milan: How does **it** confirms the package name? In a way, it _doesn't_. All Ubuntu (actually `dpkg`) knows is that is has several packages installed, `google-chrome-stable` being one of them. That package contains a bunch of files, and executables, including `/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome`, and the install script creates the soft links. `dpkg`  does not care if the names of the executables match the package name. It's just a bunch of files.

Comment: @Milan: **you** might ask `dpgk` "Which files does package X contains?" (`dpkg --listfiles <package>`), or "Which package does file Y belong to?" (`dpkg --search <file>`), both of which are irrelevant for _executing_ a given software once its package is installed.

Comment: Lastly: `/etc/alternatives` is a mechanism for choosing between _implementations_ of a given _name_, using soft links for that. It deals with _files_, not packages. If you have several text _editors_, like `nano` and `vi`. which one will be `editor` command? Or several Java versions, from different vendors, which one will be invoked when you simply type `java`? That's what the alternative system is for. So Google Chrome is creating an alternative too, maybe to allow co-existence of distinct chrome versions (stable, unstable, nightly, beta, long-term), one being your main `google-chrome`

Comment: @MestreLion: thank you so much again for your time and for such detailed replies. I appreciate that. And sorry in advance but now, I got other questions: you mentioned "All Ubuntu (actually `dpkg`) knows is that is has several packages installed, `google-chrome-stable` being one of them." But does Ubuntu (or `dpkg`) store the name of installed packages in any local file...I mean `htop` displays all the meaningful information by reading from various system files and doing some sort of calculation on it, right? So, does `dpkg` do anything like that? Sorry, if the question is too basic/off-topic!

Comment: @MestreLion: one more thing: thank you so much for sharing these very useful commands: `dpkg --listfiles <package>` & `dpkg --search <file>`. However, why did you say "both of which are irrelevant for *executing* a given software once its package is installed."? If possible, could you please elaborate a little bit more on that or share any useful articles/links where I can read more by myself?

Comment: @MestreLion: I didn't know about `/etc/alternatives` before. Thanks for sharing that one as well! You said "It deals with *files*, not packages." but, if I want to update the soft link manually then is it possible? e.g. right now, `editor` is pointing to `nano` by `editor -> /bin/nano*` but if I want to change to `gedit` then is there any `dpkg` command whose output I can use to update the soft link for `editor` in `/etc/alternatives`? I mean there are so many files for `gedit` (output of `dpkg --listfiles gedit`), so, how can I decide which file to use to update that soft link? Thanks again:)

Comment: @Milan: all great questions, all off-topic to this one. Create new questions, post me their links here and I'll gladly answer them all

Comment: Thank you so much @MestreLion for your response. Sure, that's a good idea. I would create new question(s) and post the links here! Again, I appreciate your initiative and your time.

Answer (score 1):

Those are verbose options related to each application so some apps used the -V others use -v others both or just --version. There is no general rule for naming convention.

what i mean to say is those options don't have a standard so you may find option -X in some app do the same as -R in other ...

Comment: **+1** for your time given to answer this question. But the answer which satisfied me most came from [Radu Rădeanu](http://askubuntu.com/users/147044/radu-rdeanu), and you'll also agree with this. :)

Answer (score 1):

**The standard is:**

```
app --version
```

`-v` or `-V` is only (not generally speaking) the *abbreviated* form for `--version`. You will never see in a man page something like:

```
-v
    Print version...
```

or:

```
-V
    Print version...
```

but you will see all the time these two options, the abbreviated form (if this exists) and the standard form, together. Something like:

```
-v, --version
    Print version...
```

or:

```
-V, --version
    Print version...
```

But **this depends only by developers how they want to implement their applications**. For example `-v` is used in some cases as the abbreviated form for `--verbose` (see `man wget`), or for `--invert-match` (see `man grep`) a.o., or in other cases as stand alone (see `man awk` or `man ps`).

Comment: I'm always satisfied by your answer.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It typically ends up being caused by an option called "verbosity". Verbosity runs a program and prints as much information as possible to the terminal from which it was called.

Some programs, however, don't support verbose mode or don't run in a way that would require any form of verbosity, so they will spit out the help string. Others will treat -v and -V equally.